# Eclipse Syntax error, insert "}" to complete classbody

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, sms

Im new to the forum and I am trying to code an sms application. However I keep getting this error on my code and I do not know what to do.

here is the code

```
package com.sms;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.telephony.SmsManager;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button buttonSend;
    EditText textPhoneNo;
    EditText textSMS;           
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        textPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);
        textSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);

        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String phoneNo = textPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                  String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();

                  try {
                        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();




            }
            }
        }   

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your missing an ending parenthesis near the end

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button buttonSend;
    EditText textPhoneNo;
    EditText textSMS;           
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
        textPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);
        textSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);

        buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String phoneNo = textPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();
                try {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS faild, please try again later!",     
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); statement
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }); //<-- here   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String phoneNo = textPhoneNo.getText().toString();
        String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();

           try {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
    }
});
```

You forgot to add the parenthese and semi-colon `);` at the end of the definition of `OnClickListener`.